# My javascript code will not connect to my HTML code (it just does not appear on my html website)

Tags: javascript, html, ethereum, solidity, truffle

First Thank you for taking the time and reading this:

I have been working on the problem for a while now. I am working on creating my own token/cryptocurrency on the ethereum network using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP7JNXdrToU&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgWFuKg2wbm_0GLV0Tiy1R-n&index=14) tutorial video. A few things you should know:

- I am using Ganache as a localhost
- I am using a Mac computer
- I am using the terminal to launch my HTML website with the code `npm run dev`
- I am using atom to write all my code

Now here is the javascript code that I'm getting an error with. In particular where it says `App.contracts.CinoCoinSale.deployed().then(function(instance)` anything under this function does not work. Even when I do `console.log` it does appear in my console. Its really weird and I don't know what's wrong

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0',
  loading: false,
  tokenPrice: 1000000000000000,
  tokensSold: 0,
  tokensAvailable: 750000,

  init: function() {
    console.log("App initialized...")
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContracts();
  },

  initContracts: function() {
    $.getJSON("CinoCoinSale.json", function(cinoCoinSale) {
      App.contracts.CinoCoinSale = TruffleContract(cinoCoinSale);
      App.contracts.CinoCoinSale.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
      App.contracts.CinoCoinSale.deployed().then(function(cinoCoinSale) {
        console.log("Cino Coin Sale Address:", cinoCoinSale.address);
      });
    }).done(function() {
      $.getJSON("CinoCoin.json", function(cinoCoin) {
        App.contracts.CinoCoin = TruffleContract(cinoCoin);
        App.contracts.CinoCoin.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
        App.contracts.CinoCoin.deployed().then(function(cinoCoin) {
          console.log("Cino Coin Address:", cinoCoin.address);
        });
        return App.render();
      });
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    if (App.loading) {
      return;
    }
    App.loading = true;

    var loader  = $('#loader');
    var content = $('#content');

    loader.show();
    content.hide();

    // Load account data
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if(err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $('#accountAddress').html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    })

    // Load token sale contract
    App.contracts.CinoCoinSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      cinoCoinSaleInstance = instance;
      return cinoCoinSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
    }).then(function(tokenPrice) {
      App.tokenPrice = tokenPrice;
      $('.token-price').html(web3.fromWei(App.tokenPrice, "ether").toNumber());
      return cinoCoinSaleInstance.tokensSold();
    }).then(function(tokensSold) {
      App.tokensSold = tokensSold.toNumber();
      $('.tokens-sold').html(App.tokensSold);
      $('.tokens-available').html(App.tokensAvailable);

      var progressPercent = (Math.ceil(App.tokensSold) / App.tokensAvailable) * 100;
     $('#progress').css('width', progressPercent + '%');

     // Load token contract
     App.contracts.CinoCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
       cinoCoinInstance = instance;
       return cinoCoinInstance.balanceOf(App.account);
     }).then(function(balance) {
       $('.cino-balance').html(balance.toNumber());
     })
   });

   App.loading = false;
   loader.hide();
   content.show();
  }
 },

 $(function() {
   $(window).load(function() {
     App.init();
   })
 });
```

Then here is the HTML code I am using to run my website on a localhost server. The website looks really good and its working except for one thing:
The part that does not appear and I'm having a problem with is inserting values from previous code. This might be confusing so here is an example: For the piece of code `<p><span class="tokens-sold"></span> / <span class="tokens-available"></span> tokens sold</p>` there should be values inserted for the `class="tokens-sold"` part and `class="tokens-available"` these values should be inserted from the Javascript file I think but it does not work and therefore does not show up on the website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cino Coin ICO Sale</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="width: 650px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">CINO COIN ICO SALE</h1>
            <hr/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div id="loader">
          <p class="text-center">Loading...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
          <p>
            Introducing "Cino Coin" (CC)!
            Token price is <span class="token-price"></span> Ether. You currently have <span class="dapp-balance"></span>&nbsp;CC's.
          </p>
          <br/>
          <form onSubmit="App.buyTokens(); return false;" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="numberOfTokens" class="form-control input-lg" type="number" name="number" value="1" min="1" pattern="[0-9]">
                </input>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Buy Tokens</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <br>
           <div class="progress">
              <div id="progress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
              </div>
            </div>
          <p><span class="tokens-sold"></span> / <span class="tokens-available"></span> tokens sold</p>
          <hr>
          <p id="accountAddress"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> .</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/truffle-contract.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate it so much if the solution would be found. If you need more detail to what the problem is or you don't understand the problem then just say and I will try to explain it in a different way.

Furthermore, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP7JNXdrToU&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgWFuKg2wbm_0GLV0Tiy1R-n&index=14) is the video I'm using. I am stuck at time 11:48 where token price is inserted. I have completed the rest of the video series and my code has worked so far.

Again thank you so much I really appreciate it :)

**Here is the project folder**

[This is a snapshot of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdrZG.png)

**Edit**

I have done some more research and found out that anything under the `App.contracts.CinoCoinSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {` does not work. Even when I put `console.log("hi");` it will not print out to the console. I still dont know how to solve this but maybe it helps. Its like ignoring that function for some reason

Comment: check your tree structure of project or just attach snapshot of that.

Comment: What does a tree structure mean like what do I need to include a snapshot of

Comment: your project folder structure which you can find in your ide .

Comment: I have included the project folder a screenshot hope this helps. If you need to see how the project looks like or the code just go to https://github.com/dappuniversity/token_sale this is all the code I'm using maybe compare it to mine but I have compared it and I found no mistakes maybe you can. Again hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what is under `App.contracts` maybe it did not get loaded properly. There's no way that it doesn't work with contracts object available. The worst case it should have printed the simple console that you were trying. Try to `console.log(App.contracts);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however `console.log(App.contracts);` does not work it does not print to the console. I'm not sure what you mean by checking what's under `App.contracts` could you further explain, please.

Comment: You have contracts object which you have initialized empty, so i was suggesting to check if the contracts object is available with some data before you use it

Comment: One more thing you can check is, currently you are using web3 object, but Metamask has updated the privacy. See if you have accidentally enabled it, if so your web3 object will return null and instead you have to use ethereum object. If that's the issue check this medium article for more details https://medium.com/metamask/introducing-privacy-mode-42549d4870fa

Comment: How do I check if the contracts object is available? I'm quite a beginner at this so could you please explain a bit more. The metamask privacy setting is off so that should be fine. Thank You

Comment: Another thing you should know that if I type `truffle test` in my terminal it says `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` I don't know what it means could this be the reason why it's failing?

Comment: I got it to work it was just a typo. Omg i'm so happy :) as per usual (face palm)